# Bash - Date command and space

Tags: linux, bash, date

I am trying to create a script that uses the date command in bash. I am familiar with the basic syntax of the date command.
Here is the simple script:

```
#!/bin/bash 
set -x 
DATE_COMMAND="date "+%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"" 
echo "$($DATE_COMMAND)" 
set +x
```

The thing is that the above code doesn't work. 
Here is the output:

```
+ DATE_COMMAND='date +%y-%m-%d'
+ %H:%M:%S
onlyDate: line 3: fg: no job control
+ echo ''

+ set +x
```

Ok, so the problem is that the bash splits the command because of the space. I can understand that but I don't know how to avoid that. I have tried to avoid the space with `\`, to avoid the space and the `"`. Also the single quotes doesn't seem to work.

Please note that I know that this script can be written this way:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
DATE_COMMAND=$(date "+%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

echo "$DATE_COMMAND"
set +x
```

I have tried that but I can't use this approach because I want to run the command several times in my script.

Any help will be really appreciated!

Comment: Define a Bash function for it.

Comment: Thats a really good appoach actually! But because it is driving me crazy I would really love to know why the above is not working!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The correct approach is to define your own function inside your Bash script.

```
function my_date {
  date "+%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
}
```

Now you can use `my_date` as if it were an external program.

For example:

```
echo "It is now $(my_date)."
```

Or simply:

```
my_date
```

**Why isn't your approach working?**

The first problem is that your assignment is broken.

```
DATE_COMMAND="date "+%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S""
```

This is parsed as an assignment of the string `date +%y-%m-%d` to the variable `DATE_COMMAND`.  After the blank, the shell starts interpreting the remaining symbols in ways you did not intend.

This could be partially fixed by changing the quotation.

```
DATE_COMMAND="date '+%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'"
```

However, this doesn't really solve the problem because if we now use

```
echo $($DATE_COMMAND)
```

It will not expand the argument correctly.  The `date` program will see the arguments `'+%y-%m-%d` and `%H:%M:%S'` (with quotes) instead of a single string.  This could be solved by using `eval` as in

```
DATE_COMMAND="date '+%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'"
echo $(eval $DATE_COMMAND)
```

where the variable `DATE_COMMAND` is first expanded to the string `date '+%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'` that is then `eval`uated as if it were written like so thus invoking `date` correctly.

Note that I'm only showing this to explain the issue.  `eval` is not a good solution here.  Use a function instead.

PS It is better to avoid all-uppercase identifier strings as those are often in conflict with environment variables or even have a magic meaning to the shell.

Answer (score 9):

Escaping the space works for me.

```
echo `date +%d.%m.%Y\ %R.%S.%3N`
```

Comment: Works for me - DATE_FORMAT=\`date +%Y-%m-%d\ %H:%M:%S\`

Answer (score 2):

For long scripts

declare variables section:

```
dateformat="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
```

anywhere to get date:

```
datestr=`date +"${dateformat}"`
```

anywhere to echo date:

```
echo ${datestr}
```

For short simple scripts DaniëlGu's answer is the best:

```
echo `date +%d.%m.%Y\ %R.%S.%3N`
```

Answer (score 1):

Shortest answer is

```
#if you want to store in a variable
now=$(date '+%F" "%T');
echo $now

#or direct output
date '+%F" "%T'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using:

```
DF="+%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S";
FILE_DATE=$(date "${DF[@]}" -r "${SCHEMA_LOCAL_PATH}.gz");
```

Seems Bash treats space in $DF as an array's separator and 'date' receives 2 agruments instead of one so I'm sending an array.

Also works for me (check "+" sign):

```
DF="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S";
FILE_DATE=$(date +"${DF}" -r "${SCHEMA_LOCAL_PATH}.gz");
```