# date command not found in shell script

Tags: sh

my shell script backup.sh as below, when i execute this script, i got the error `"date: command not found"`. I have checked that there are no space between `=` and the parameters.
Could anydody give an explain about this error.
Thanks.

```
x00004:/home/ # cat backup.sh 
#!/bin/sh
set +x

source ./conf.sh

if [ $# != 2 ] ; then
    echo " Usage: $0 [sftp user] [sftp pwd]"
    exit 1;
fi

DATE=`date +%y-%m-%d--%H:%M:%S`
echo "${DATE}"
file=test.tar.gz
echo "Starting to backup files..."

#to backup files to sftp server

x00004:/home/ # ./backup.sh usr pwd
./backup.sh: line 11: date: command not found

Starting to backup files...
x00004:/home/poc/src #
```

Comment: Check the `PATH` environment variable

Comment: show your conf.sh , it must be restricting path to your current directory

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bash - Date command and space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27337757/bash-date-command-and-space)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Shells can't find commands if the commands aren't in directories in `$PATH`. Quick fix: replace `date` with `/bin/date`. However, a similar problem might occur in conf.sh or backup.sh, so a more global solution is to echo "$PATH" at the beginning of your script, figure out what's missing, and and fix it, e.g., `PATH=/bin:$PATH`.

Answer (score 2):

Best way is to use the bash/shell command called `command -v` to dynamically check where is your date path.

```
DATE_BIN=$(command -v date)
DATE=`${DATE_BIN} +%y-%m-%d--%H:%M:%S`
```